# Having trouble with sql LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `alerts` WHERE `title` LIKE `%template%`
```

This should return at least 3 results with titles that includes the word 'template' but I'm getting the following error: -

## 1054 - Unknown column '%template%' in 'where clause'

As far as I can tell its syntactically correct and calling the correct column names. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single quotes for the `%template%`:

```
SELECT * FROM `alerts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%template%'
```

Comment: Legend thanks! you know when you've been looking at it too long when you miss something like that, thanks mate.